# Misidentification of "Z" as "2" IronOCR C#

Tags: c#, nuget, ocr

I'm trying to develop an OCR project using IronOCR Nuget (C#).
The input is a scanned nonsearchable PDF file, it works just fine, except for one thing, in some of the cases, it detects the letter "Z" (Capital) as "2"(usually when "Z" appears as the first letter of the pattern I'm trying to retrieve).

I was trying to apply different [optimization filters](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/examples/ocr-image-filters-for-net-tesseract/), but none of them helped me get the desired output.

Since I'm only at the beginning of the project I assume that more of those misidentifications will occur, such as:
[image]

My question is, how can I avoid the "Z" and "2" misidentification (and other misidentifications)?

Comment: i would contact the developer of that package

Comment: um @KJ OCR doesn't mean `One Char Replace` - it means `Optical Character Recognition`

Answer (score 0):

The most important factor will be the quality of your input. IronOCR works best with images around 200-225 DPI. Lossless image types such as PNG and TIF give better results over lossy types like JPG.

IronOCR returns a full Results Object Class which includes a **[Character.Confidence](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/object-reference/api/IronOcr.OcrResult.OcrResultTextElement.html)** value, and lists output alternative symbols choices and their probability also, which can be very useful for spell-checking:

```
double CharacterOcrAccuracy = Character.Confidence;    
OcrResult.Choice[] Choices = Character.Choices;
```

Here's a full code example:
https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/examples/results-objects/

```
// We can delve deep into OCR results as an object model of
// Pages, Barcodes, Paragraphs, Lines, Words and Characters
// This allows us to explore, export and draw OCR content using other APIs

var Ocr = new IronTesseract();
Ocr.Configuration.EngineMode = TesseractEngineMode.TesseractAndLstm;

using (var Input = new OcrInput(@"example.tiff"))
{
OcrResult Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
foreach (var Page in Result.Pages)
{
    // Page object
    int PageNumber = Page.PageNumber;
    string PageText = Page.Text;
    int PageWordCount = Page.WordCount;
    // null if we dont set Ocr.Configuration.ReadBarCodes = true;
    OcrResult.Barcode[] Barcodes = Page.Barcodes;
    System.Drawing.Bitmap PageImage = Page.ToBitmap(Input);
    int PageWidth = Page.Width;
    int PageHeight = Page.Height;
    int PagRotation = Page.Rotation; // angular correction in degrees from OcrInput.Deskew()
    
    foreach (var Paragraph in Page.Paragraphs)
    {
        // Pages -> Paragraphs
        int ParagraphNumber = Paragraph.ParagraphNumber;
        String ParagraphText = Paragraph.Text;
        System.Drawing.Bitmap ParagraphImage = Paragraph.ToBitmap(Input);
        int ParagraphX_location = Paragraph.X;
        int ParagraphY_location = Paragraph.Y;
        int ParagraphWidth = Paragraph.Width;
        int ParagraphHeight = Paragraph.Height;
        double ParagraphOcrAccuracy = Paragraph.Confidence;
        OcrResult.TextFlow paragrapthText_direction = Paragraph.TextDirection;
        foreach (var Line in Paragraph.Lines)
        {
            // Pages -> Paragraphs -> Lines
            int LineNumber = Line.LineNumber;
            String LineText = Line.Text;
            System.Drawing.Bitmap LineImage = Line.ToBitmap(Input); ;
            int LineX_location = Line.X;
            int LineY_location = Line.Y;
            int LineWidth = Line.Width;
            int LineHeight = Line.Height;
            double LineOcrAccuracy = Line.Confidence;
            double LineSkew = Line.BaselineAngle;
            double LineOffset = Line.BaselineOffset;
            foreach (var Word in Line.Words)
            {
                // Pages -> Paragraphs -> Lines -> Words
                int WordNumber = Word.WordNumber;
                String WordText = Word.Text;
                System.Drawing.Image WordImage = Word.ToBitmap(Input);
                int WordX_location = Word.X;
                int WordY_location = Word.Y;
                int WordWidth = Word.Width;
                int WordHeight = Word.Height;
                double WordOcrAccuracy = Word.Confidence;
                if (Word.Font != null)
                {
                    // Word.Font is only set when using Tesseract Engine Modes rather than LTSM
                    String FontName = Word.Font.FontName;
                    double FontSize = Word.Font.FontSize;
                    bool IsBold = Word.Font.IsBold;
                    bool IsFixedWidth = Word.Font.IsFixedWidth;
                    bool IsItalic = Word.Font.IsItalic;
                    bool IsSerif = Word.Font.IsSerif;
                    bool IsUnderLined = Word.Font.IsUnderlined;
                    bool IsFancy = Word.Font.IsCaligraphic;
                }
                foreach (var Character in Word.Characters)
                {
                    // Pages -> Paragraphs -> Lines -> Words -> Characters
                    int CharacterNumber = Character.CharacterNumber;
                    String CharacterText = Character.Text;
                    System.Drawing.Bitmap CharacterImage = Character.ToBitmap(Input);
                    int CharacterX_location = Character.X;
                    int CharacterY_location = Character.Y;
                    int CharacterWidth = Character.Width;
                    int CharacterHeight = Character.Height;
                    double CharacterOcrAccuracy = Character.Confidence;
                    // Output alternative symbols choices and their probability.
                    // Very useful for spellchecking
                    OcrResult.Choice[] Choices = Character.Choices;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```